# Is there a reliable way to convert a naive UTC time stamp to local time with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, timezone

Determining a user's timezone server side and converting from UTC has proven more trouble than its worth.

Is there a reliable way for javascript/jquery to determine the timezone of the user and apply the offset to a UTC datetime stamp (2012-08-25 10:59:56.511479) and output in my desired format (Aug 25 '12 - 10:59AM)?

What might the jquery code look like to say

```
// dom ready
$('span.localtime').each(function(e) {
    // get stamp and apply conversion
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.getTimezoneOffset()` is available on the date object, and gives you the offset from UTC in minutes.

```
var offset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset();

// convert myUtcDate to a date in local time
myUtcDate.setMinutes(myUtcDate.getMinutes() + (offset*-1));
```

Thus:

```
$('.span.localtime').each(function() {
   var myUtcDate = new Date($(this).html()); // assuming "2012-08-25 10:59:56.511479"
   myUtcDate.setMinutes(myUtcDate.getMinutes() + (myUtcDate.getTimezoneOffset() * -1));

   $(this).html(myUtcDate.toString());
});
```

Note that `myUtcDate.toString()` could be replaced with any date formatting you want. In your case, it might look like

```
$(this).html(formatDate(myUtcDate));

function formatDate(d) {

   var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

    var y = d.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2); // "12"
    var m = months[d.getMonth()]; // "Aug"
    var d = d.getDate(); // "25"

    var ampm = 'AM';
    var h = d.getHours();

    if(h>=12) {
        h -= 12;
        ampm = 'PM';
    }

    if(h == 0)
       h = 12;

    var min = ("00" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

    return m + " " + d + " '" + y + " - " + h + ":" + min + ampm;
}
```

You might want to use a [date format plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat) for formatting dates in a neater more reliable manner.

Comment: Ok so if jinja sends the UTC stamp to html, how do I apply the date.timezoneoffset minutes to it?

Comment: Am I reading this wrong? If I am at UTC -5, that's -300 minutes. So when u do setminutes + (-300 * -1), aren't u adding 5 hours?

Comment: @chrickso: you'd think so, hey! but `.getTimezoneOffset()` will yield `300` if you are in `UTC -5`. [*The time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and local time. Note that this means that the offset is positive if the local timezone is behind UTC and negative if it is ahead.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

Comment: Are their any browsers/instances where the .getTimezoneOffset() is known to not work/misbehave? Thank you very much for this code

Comment: @chrickso: Not that I'm aware of. All major browsers supports it. You might want to know that it takes daylight savings into consideration, which is probably what you want, and also that for most browsers you'll need to restart the browser if you've changed time zone on your computer.

Comment: this code did work great but there is a flash of the unstyled date which i'd like to avoid. i realize i could hide it and show it on DOM ready but it is between other text so it still looks jumpy. i don't want to hide the whole line. any other suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: @chrickso: I would not recommend running any javascript that manuipulates the DOM before DOMReady. So if you want to do this in JavaScript, you're going to have to wait for DOMReady. One option would be to do the conversion at the server side instead. In that case you have to make sure that the client passes information about time zone, perhaps in a cookie. The exact implementation would of course depend on the serverside environment. But I must say DOMReady is usually really quick, and you shouldn't notice the flickering. Are you sure you're running it in DOMReady and not body onload?

Comment: thanks. i have looked into the server side and fell back to client side as a last resort. the only reliable way to determine client timezone from the server is to a) store it as a setting or b) use an IP lookup service. Neither strikes me as awesome. I did try this at DOMReady and it was very fast but I could notice it and drove me nuts :( thanks again for all your time, i hope this code will be useful to someone in the future

Answer (score 0):

Also, have a look at https://github.com/GregDThomas/jquery-localtime - it wraps all this up in a simple to use jQuery plugin.